# Dell Wifi not working in inspiron 1545

Tags: 12.10

I am new bee to ubuntu. And I have installed ubuntu 12.10 in dell inspiron 1545 but my wifi isnt working. From where do I can found driver ? Or what should I do to work wifi ?

Thank you

Comment: Most possibly this will solve the issue - http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-sta-wireless-card-bcm43xx. If you have broadcom wireless (common to inspiron 1545)

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!

Ubuntu may have not installed the proprietary drivers you need. This is because Ubuntu tries to stay free by itself, but these drivers are non-free. However, they can make your computer work better.

To do so, open up the Ubuntu Software Center. It's the icon that sort of looks like a shopping bag (with explosives).

Move your mouse over the bar at the very top and click `Edit`. Select `Software Sources...`. Give your computer a second to crank, and then a window will appear called `Software Sources`. Select the tab labeled `Additional Drivers`. Let it load, and if any drivers appear, tell Ubuntu to install them.

If the list is empty or all of them are in use, open a terminal by clicking the Ubuntu Logo on the top left and typing "terminal". When the black window opens, run these commands: `lspci` and `rfkill list all`. Edit the question and tell us what it said.

Answer (score 1):

**dell inspiron 1545** uses **broadcom** wireless.

Following installed wifi on my *dell inspiron 1545* in *Ubuntu 12.10*

`sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic`
`sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source`
`sudo modprobe wl`

You may need to prss <kbd>Fn+F2</kbd> (1 or more time ) to enable wireless. Check the `network manager` on panel after every press.